# getBitmap deprecated in API 29 java android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, gallery

I am developing an android application I want user to select an image from gallery. But I have seen that `getBitmap` is deprecated on API 29

I have tried `ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(Imagedecoder.createSource())` but it crashes the application

```
if (requestCode == GALLERY){
            if (data != null) {
                Uri contentURI = data.getData();
                try {
                    if (contentURI!=null){
                        bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(getContentResolver(), contentURI));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                    dialog.show();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

I am not getting that why app is crashing.

here is crash log

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/graphics/ImageDecoder;
        at com.example.myapplication.ProfileView.onActivityResult(ProfileView.java:313)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3632)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5354)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.graphics.ImageDecoder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at com.example.myapplication.ProfileView.onActivityResult(ProfileView.java:313) 
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3632) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3679) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5354) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.graphics.ImageDecoder
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 14 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: "But it crashes the application" What is the exception you get here?

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/graphics/ImageDecoder;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Documentation of [public static Bitmap getBitmap (ContentResolver cr, 
                Uri url)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html#getBitmap(android.content.ContentResolver,%2520android.net.Uri))

> This method was deprecated in API level 29. loading of images should
>   be performed through [ImageDecoder#createSource(ContentResolver, Uri)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder.html#createSource(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri)),
>   which offers modern features like [PostProcessor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PostProcessor.html).

---

Example algorithm can be

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29){
    // To handle deprication use   
    ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(Imagedecoder.createSource())
} else{
    // Use older version
    MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageUri)
}
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this function but it crashes the app

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/graphics/ImageDecoder;

Comment: That error is becuase you are verifying your code in below 29 devices. This method has been added in 29 and not available in even 28. So use both methods to hanldedaprication

Comment: not working for me..it gives me result as  : unexpected error unsupported bitmap configuration : "Hardware"